# Error: Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing **Error: Value for argument "data " on firebase.**

**situation**

> I tried to access from local but it didn't work.............

Could you confirm my error?

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');


admin.initializeApp();


exports.getScreams = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  admin.firestore().collection('screams').get()
    .then(data => {
      let screams
      data.forEach( doc =>  {
        screams.push(doc.data());
      });
      return res.json(screams);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
});


exports.createScreams = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
   const newScreams = {
    body: req.body.body,
    userHandle: req.body.userHandle,
    createdAt: admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date())
   };

   admin
   .firestore()
   .collection('screams')
   .add(newScreams)
   .then(doc => {
     res.json({Message: 'document ${doc.id} created successfully'});
   })
   .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went wrong'});
    });
    console.error(err);
});
```

**screenshot**

[image]

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text.  Copy the text into the question itself so it's easier to read, copy, and search.  Also, for error messages, it's helpfuf if you point out which line of your code is causing it, using what you see in the output, and what you did that caused the error.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson Thank you for advice. I got it.

Comment: You can edit the question to make corrections using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be data.docs:

```
  data.docs.forEach(doc =>  {
    screams.push(doc.data());
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message says that `body` in the new document data has a value of `undefined`, which is not valid. Since you set `body` like this:

```
body: req.body.body
```

It seems that `req.body.body` does not exist. Did you mean to use `req.body`?

If the `req.body.body` is correct, but it really has no value, you can now [tell Firestore to ignore the `undefined`](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/pull/1062) and thus not add a field. To do this, you'll need to call the following before reading/writing anything:

```
const firestore  = admin.firestore();
firestore.settings({ignoreUndefinedProperties:true});
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution and another error has occurred that's"ReferenceError: err is not defined at exports.createScreams.functions.https.onRequest" .